# Getting website thumbnails in a webkit extension

Tags: api, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm wondering if the WebKit browsers (Safari and/or Chrome) provide a method to generate or retrieve existing thumbnails for websites. If not, is there any way to generate these client-side? If even that is not possible, is there software or a particular API to generate thumbnails server-side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To people from the future:

At the time of writing, this feature is only available in Safari 5.0+. You can get thumbnails from the [Tabs API](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/SafariBrowserTab/SafariBrowserTab.html). Chrome doesn't have any similar features as far as I could find.

Comment: I stand corrected! This feature is available for both Safari and Chrome